# create separate array element based on condition

Tags: arrays, dataframe, pyspark

I have below array in dataframe

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|typed_phone_numbers                              |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|[-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST]           |
|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB]         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to create another element within the array if PHONE and FAX both are present in first element. if there is only phone or fax no need to create another element.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|typed_phone_numbers                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|["-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST","-222222-FAX-17-TEST"]    |
|["-2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB","-1111111-FAX-17-TESTB"] |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example in the text of your question, including the code for what you've tried.

Comment: I don't have a single clue how to achieve that scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can split on both **`-`** and **`~`**, remove none, check if **`phone and fax both exist`**(using higher order function **`filter`**) in **`when`** clause, then apply your logic using **`element_at,concat and concat_ws.`**    **`(spark2.4+)`**

```
#sample data
#df.show()
#+----------------------------------------+
#|typed_phone_numbers                     |
#+----------------------------------------+
#|[-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST]  |
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB]|
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE]             |
#+----------------------------------------+  



from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("yo", F.split(F.col("typed_phone_numbers")[0], '\-|~'))\
  .withColumn("yo", F.expr("""filter(yo,x-> x!='')"""))\
  .withColumn("typed_phone_numbers", F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(yo,x-> x='PHONE' or x='FAX')"""))==2,\
                           F.array(F.concat(F.lit('-'),F.concat_ws('-',F.element_at("yo",1),\
                                                   F.element_at("yo",3),\
                                                   F.element_at("yo",5),\
                                                   F.element_at("yo",6))),\
                           F.concat(F.lit('-'),F.concat_ws('-',F.element_at("yo",2),\
                                                   F.element_at("yo",4),\
                                                   F.element_at("yo",5),\
                                                   F.element_at("yo",6)))))\
              .otherwise(F.col("typed_phone_numbers"))).drop("yo").show(truncate=False)


#+---------------------------------------------------+
#|typed_phone_numbers                                |
#+---------------------------------------------------+
#|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST, -222222-FAX-17-TEST]   |
#|[-2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB, -1111111-FAX-17-TESTB]|
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE]                        |
#+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

Use **`higher order function`** transform to apply your logic to each element.

```
#sample data
#df.show()
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|typed_phone_numbers                                                           |
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST]                                        |
#|[-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST, -2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB]|
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB]                                      |
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE]                                                   |
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df\
  .withColumn("yo", F.expr("""(transform(typed_phone_numbers,x-> split(substring(x,2,length(x)),'\-|~')))"""))\
  .withColumn("typed_phone_numbers",F.when(F.size(F.expr("""filter(yo[0],x->x='PHONE' or x='FAX')"""))==2,\
                          F.flatten(F.expr("""transform(yo,y->\
                                                   array(concat('-',concat_ws('-',y[0],y[2],y[4],y[5])),\
                                                         concat('-',concat_ws('-',y[1],y[3],y[4],y[5]))))""")))\
                          .otherwise(F.col("typed_phone_numbers")))\
                          .drop("yo").show(truncate=False)


#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|typed_phone_numbers                                                                                |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST, -222222-FAX-17-TEST]                                                   |
#|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST, -222222-FAX-17-TEST, -2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB, -1111111-FAX-17-TESTB]|
#|[-2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB, -1111111-FAX-17-TESTB]                                                |
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE]                                                                        |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you can have **`single PHONE or single FAX`**, **`in any array row`**(even with other **`PHONE+FAX`**), you could use this.

```
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|typed_phone_numbers                                                           |
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST, -2812597115~1111111-PHONE]             |
#|[-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST, -2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB]|
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB, -2812597115~1111111-FAX]             |
#|[-2812597115~1111111-PHONE]                                                   |
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df\
  .withColumn("yo", F.expr("""(transform(typed_phone_numbers,x-> split(substring(x,2,length(x)),'\-|~')))"""))\
  .withColumn("typed_phone_numbers",\
                          F.flatten(F.expr("""transform(yo,y->\
                          IF((array_contains(y,'PHONE')==True) and (array_contains(y,'FAX')==True),\
                                                   array(concat('-',concat_ws('-',y[0],y[2],y[4],y[5])),\
                                                         concat('-',concat_ws('-',y[1],y[3],y[4],y[5]))),\
                                                         array(concat('-',concat_ws('-',y)))))""")))\
                          .drop("yo").show(truncate=False)


#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|typed_phone_numbers                                                                                |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST, -222222-FAX-17-TEST, -2812597115-1111111-PHONE]                        |
#|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST, -222222-FAX-17-TEST, -2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB, -1111111-FAX-17-TESTB]|
#|[-2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB, -1111111-FAX-17-TESTB, -2812597115-1111111-FAX]                       |
#|[-2812597115-1111111-PHONE]                                                                        |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what if there is multiple element in array this code will look for first element of array for example ['-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST','-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB'] in this case code will work for only 0th element

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `regexp_replace(str, string-pattern, replacement-pattern)` and `split(col, string-pattern)` like so

#### Your data

```
data = [
    (['-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST'],),
    (['-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB'],),
    (['-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST'],),
    (['-2812597115-FAX-17-TESTB'],)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['typed_phone_numbers'])
```

#### Solution

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, split
(
    df.
        withColumn(
            'typed_phone_numbers',
            split(
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace(
                        col('typed_phone_numbers')[0],
                        '^(-\\d+)(~\\d+)(-PHONE)(~FAX)(-\\d+-\\w+)$',
                        '$1$3$5,$2$4$5'
                    ),
                    '~',
                    '-'
                ),
                ','
            )
        ).
        show(truncate=False)
)
+---------------------------------------------------+                           
|typed_phone_numbers                                |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST, -222222-FAX-17-TEST]   |
|[-2812597115-PHONE-17-TESTB, -1111111-FAX-17-TESTB]|
|[-5594162570-PHONE-17-TEST]                        |
|[-2812597115-FAX-17-TESTB]                         |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what if there is multiple element in array this code will look for first element of array for example  ['-5594162570~222222-PHONE~FAX-17-TEST','-2812597115~1111111-PHONE~FAX-17-TESTB'] in this case code will work for only 0th element